# Open file and load it

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm creating a program that uses a specific file type and i've associated that file type with the program, but when i click the file, it only starts the program, but it doesn't load the file I clicked. How can I make my program load the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `static void Main(string[] args)` to get the filename.

I'd do something like this:

somewhere in your code you should have a string variable where to store the retrieved filename `private string filename;`

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  // first check if there are arguments
  if (args.length > 0)
  {
     // check if the filename has the right extension
     if (args[0].EndsWith(".ext"))
     {
        // check for existence
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(args[0]))
        {
           // it exists.. so store the filename in the previously defined variable
           filename = args[0];
        }
     }
  }
}
```

This way you can do one kind of logic when the filename variable has content and another kind of logic when it hasn't.

Hope you can use this.

Answer (score 3):

When you open a file you've associated with your application, the file path is passed into your program as a command line argument. You can load the file yourself like so:

```
string fileName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

In your app you have to use `Main(string[] args)` and get from args params passed to your application.
Here it is an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0) return;
    string text = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
}
```

Comment: ...and i think you need to specify the parameter within your windows file association as shown here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749986.aspx

Comment: @zoidbeck: yes, but OP is telling us his application is opened when he double-clicks on target file, so I think this is already ok

Comment: Ok, haven't tried and thought this '%1' as Parameter had to be set explicitly. Good to know ...or as the upvotes seem to show you have to set it explicitly to get it or use the environment :-)

Comment: @zoidbeck: when you set your extension to be managed from `path_to_app\app_name.exe %1`, your application will be invoked and the first parameter on command line passed to it is filename you double-clicked on

Comment: actually i thought that was what jamiro14 requested to be done.